# shell_exec() haven't the permission to reboot/shutdown raspberry pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i try to use shell_exec() from my php web application the simple commandes by example "ls" works but with sudo not working:

*shell_exec("sudo reboot");*

this is the link :

*http://192.168.1.8/controle/webshell.php?commande=sudo%20reboot*

but the commande cannot be executed.

Any help ?

Comment: Does not SUDO ask for a password?

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) on askubuntu. You need to find out what user your webserver is running as first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with this modification in /etc/sudoers :

*www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/halt*